# UITextView won't rotate

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage, uitextview

I'm adding a text label on top of a UIImage. I am successfully able to add the text label, however I would like to rotate it 90 degrees so that it's vertical.

This is the code that I have:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.width,image.size.height)];

UITextView *myText = [[UITextView alloc] init];
myText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"font-name" size:300.0f];
myText.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
myText.text = @"Text";
myText.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[myText setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-90* M_PI/180)];

CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(image.size.width,image.size.height);
CGSize expectedLabelSize = [myText.text sizeWithFont:myText.font
                                   constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize
                                       lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];


myText.frame = CGRectMake(image.size.width - expectedLabelSize.width, image.size.height - expectedLabelSize.height, image.size.width, image.size.height);

[[UIColor whiteColor] set];
[myText.text drawInRect:myText.frame withFont:myText.font];
UIImage *myNewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

I tried transforming the Text View using this:

```
[myText setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-90* M_PI/180)];
```

as well as:

```
[myText setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI / 2)];
```

But it's not working at all, nothing happens. Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Can you use a `UILabel` instead of a `UITextView`?

Comment: @3308310 I tried changing it to a 'UILabel' but it did not have any effect.

Answer (score 2):

You are drawing the text using `[myText.text drawInRect:myText.frame withFont:myText.font];` but you are rotating the view that you are getting the text from. If you want to draw a string this way you need to rotate the context then draw. For example:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextRotateCTM(context,-M_PI / 2);
[myText.text drawInRect:myText.frame withFont:myText.font];
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

This will essentially rotate the canvas, draw the string, then rotate the canvas back.

It is likely easier to just rotate a view with a transparent background though.

Comment: I see! However after rotating it this way, it seems like the text goes outside the image itself, as it's not visible. Do I need to create a new CGRectMake?

Comment: You will need to work out the geometry yourself, but I would assume, at the very least, you'll want to flip width and height for your image (e.g. `CGRectMake(image.size.height - expectedLabelSize.width, image.size.width - expectedLabelSize.height, image.size.height, image.size.width);`) Though it is very hard to debug this without any visual representation.